# How do I complete an array of information with async calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code to fill an array with info about all books a person owns:

```
async getAllInfo(person_id)
{

    let book_list = await this.getBooks(person_id);

    for(let book in book_list)
    {
        book_list[book]["book_info"] = await this.getBookInfo(book_list[book]["book_id"])
    }

    return book_list;
}
```

When I run the getBooks I get:

```
[
    {
        "name": "BookA",
        "book_id" : "123"
    },
    {
        "Name": "BookB",
        "book_id" : "456"
    }
]
```

And then I complete the info about the book in the for loop:

```
[
    {
        "name": "BookA",
        "book_id" : "123",
        "book_info": {
            "author": "authorA",
            "publish_year": 1900
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "BookB",
        "book_id" : "456",
        "book_info": {
            "author": "authorB",
            "publish_year": 1900
        }
    }
]
```

The getBooks and getBookInfo are http calls and when a person have lots of books it may take some time to get all the information. Is is possible to get it simultaneously for all books in the array? I tried to remove the await and use the Promise.all(), but I always get:

```
[
    {
        "name": "BookA",
        "book_id" : "123",
        "book_info": {
            "domain": {
                "domain": null,
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 1,
                "members": []
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "BookB",
        "book_id" : "456",
        "book_info": {
            "domain": {
                "domain": null,
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 1,
                "members": []
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in this piece of code can be optimised:

```
for(let book in book_list) {
    book_list[book]["book_info"] = await this.getBookInfo(book_list[book]["book_id"])
}
```

Because for each book your making a request and waiting for this request to complete before fetching the details of the next book. Here is how you can perform all the requests at once and wait for all the details of the books to be retrieved:

```
async getAllInfo(person_id) {

    let book_list = await this.getBooks(person_id);

    // Creating an array of Promises to fetch the details of all the books simultaneously
    const fetchingBooksDetails = book_list.map(book => this.getBookInfo(book.book_id));

    // Wainting for the requests to complete
    const booksDetails = await Promise.all(fetchingBooksDetails);

    // Saving the details of the book in the book_list variable
    booksDetails.forEach((bookDetails, index) => {
      book_list[index].book_info = bookDetails;
    });

    return book_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested)

```
async getAllInfo(person_id)
{

    let book_list = await this.getBooks(person_id);
    for(let book in book_list)
    {
        book_list[book]["book_info"] = this.getBookInfo(book_list[book]["book_id"])
    }

    await Promise
      .all(book_list[book].map(b => b.book_info))
      .then(infos => {
        for (book in infos)
          book_list[book]["book_info"] = infos[book];
        });
    return book_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllInfo(person_id){
    return getBooks(person_id).then(function(book_list){

        var promiseArray = []
        book_list.forEach(function(book,index){
            promiseArray.push(getBookInfo(book_list[index]["book_id"]))
        })
        return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(values){
            book_list.forEach(function(book,index){
                book_list[index]["book_info"] = values[index]
            })
            return book_list
        })

    })

}
function getBooks(person_id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        resolve(
        [
            {
                "name": "BookA",
                "book_id" : "123"
            },
            {
                "Name": "BookB",
                "book_id" : "456"
            }
        ]
        )
    })

}
function getBookInfo(book_id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(book_id=="123"){
        resolve({
            "author": "authorA",
            "publish_year": 1900
        })
    }
    else if(book_id=="456"){
            resolve({
            "author": "authorB",
            "publish_year": 1900
        })
    }
    else{
        reject()
    }
})
}
getAllInfo("rap_mosnter").then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```